# Data Transformation in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

Because I am using Google Form to collect data. The source of data is not what I want so I need to create a tab and transform the data.

Here is an example of the Google Sheet (Exported from Google Form)

```
Group Leader    Groupmate  Gender  Groupmate  Gender  Groupmate  Gender
Leader 1        John       M       Mary       F       Linda      F
Leader 2        KK         F       Johanna    F
Leader 3        Rick       M
```

As you can see each row have different number of groupmate. I would like to transform the table into this

```
Group Leader    Groupmate  Gender
Leader 1        John       M     
Leader 1        Mary       F
Leader 1        Linda      F
Leader 2        KK         F
Leader 2        Johanna    F
Leader 3        Rick       M
```

I believe Groupmate name is sort of unique so I think it is possible to merge several columns and then lookup the leader name by index-match.

Lastly I would like to know if there are ways to build a Google Form with repeating questions, without me repeating the fields in the form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Overview

There a lot of ways to do this. Below is a formula using custom [arrays](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en) and [QUERY](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343?hl=en) in order to have a short but "low maintenance" formula

## Formula

```
=QUERY(
  {
    "Group Leader","Groupmate","Gender";
    A2:C;
    A2:A,D2:E;
    A2:A,F2:G
  },
  "select * where Col3 <> ''"
)
```

Note: The above works for spreasheets that use `.` as decimal separator. In case that you spreadsheet use `,` as decimal separator, replace the `,` by `\`.

Comment: Thanks. Since the form output is static I think "low maintenance" solution is good enough

Comment: But one thing I wanna ask, after I use you method. How can I get those item sorted?

Comment: Sorry, "Order by" fix the problem

Comment: I added a link to the help article about arrays and QUERY (: By the way, in this context, "low maintenance" is better than "high maintenance"

Comment: Hi, do you think you could have a chance to take a look at the following question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47863297/google-sheets-query-function-cant-copy-data). Thanks